# Any way to apply transform to a part of control?

Tags: c#, wpf

For example, translate a part of control to another place.. is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Transform can only be applied on whole control or element and not on it's parts.

What you can do is instead of applying the transform to control itself, apply it to child element.

Comment: Or re-template and apply the transform to a part of the new control template

Answer (score -1):

Sure, just apply the transform to the part of the control you want to transform.